# insert using implode or prepared statements?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, insert, prepared-statement

I have an array $authors with some numbers I want to insert into a table.

I can have a prepared statement to execute multiple times for each element from the array:

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO authors (article_id, user_id) VALUES(?, ?)');
$stmt->bindParam(1, $article_id);
$stmt->bindParam($author);
foreach($authors as $author) {
    $stmt->execute();
}
```

However, I can do a trick using `implode()` and execute the statement only once:

```
// here probably $authors = array_map('intval', $authors);
$stmt = $pdo->prepare(
    'INSERT INTO authors (article_id, user_id)
     VALUES ('.implode(', :article_id), (', $authors).', :article_id)');

$stmt->execute([':article_id' => $article_id]);
```

1. The first solution is more conventional and looks more securely.
2. The second (I think) is faster because there is only one query to the database. (and is shorter - there are no loops except in `implode`)

   - I don't see any security issues here but it looks safer (to me) when there are no string concatenations in queries.

Which is the proper way in this situation?

Edit: `echo` of the second query gives this:

```
INSERT INTO authors (article_id, student_id)
     VALUES (121, :article_id), (50, :article_id)
```

And executes with no errors.

Comment: *Err.* Have you even run both codes ? Second one won't work. Placeholders **must be unique!**

Comment: All I can think of here is _If it aint broke, dont fix it_ or break it in this case

Comment: @Rizier123 when I tested it I did it without placeholders, and rewrote it here.

Comment: @Rizier123 there is no problem using the same placehoder multiple times, tested it now!

Comment: Emulation mode turned on?

Comment: @Rizier123 in the connection I do have only default errmode and fetchmode set. Nothing else..

Comment: @RiggsFolly both ones work, you mean the first one is better, I suppose?

Comment: Well as the second dog does not actually hunt, I would stick to what works

Answer (score 1):

According to the PDO's doc "You cannot use a named parameter marker of the same name more than once in a prepared statement, unless emulation mode is on.". So that alone makes your "implode" solution bad.

That being said, I'll answer on the theory. The point of prepared statements is to compile the query only once, so repeated executions are faster. So prepared statements are meant to be used as in your first example : one simple "template" query, repeated many times.

In your second example, you make a custom query, that will hardly ever be repeated (since it's based on the content of your $authors array). Therefore, prepared statement in this case is completely useless, you have the overhead of the PREPARE without the benefits of repeated executions. **It's not the way it's supposed to be used.**

Extended insert is a perfectly valid solution, and a good one with that, but use it with normal query (i.e. `exec()`), and be sure to use `quote()` to protect against SQL-injection!